# Recursion with three variables.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion

For u(a,b,c) is a function of a,b,c $\in Z $,

We have the recursive relationships: $$u(a,b,c)=1/6[u(a-1,b+1,c)+u(a-1,b,c+1)+u(a,b-1,c+1)+u(a+1,b-1,c)+u(a,b+1,c-1)+u(a+1,b,c-1)]+1$$

and constraints: 1)$u(1,1,1)=1$;2)$u(a,b,c)=0$ if any of a or b or c =0; 3) for $(x,y,z)$ is a re-permutation of $(a,b,c)$, we have $u(x,y,z)=u(a,b,c)$

Can anyone give me some hints on how to derive the close-form expression of u(a,b,c)?

Comment: I think this formula is not well defined. To calculate $u(a,b,c)$, you need to know values for some $u(a+1,b',c')$, which require you to know some values for some $u(a+2,b',c')$,  and so on. If $a>1$, then there is no chance for this procedure to stop. For example, how would you calculate $u(2,1,1)$?

Comment: One possible solution is $u(a,b,c)=0$ for all inputs.

Comment: Thanks for Strichcoder and Mike. As you have pointed out, I found the previous setting is not very well-defined nor meaningful (seems to have $u\equiv 0$ as the only solution), so I changed it to be more meaningful.

Comment: @achillehui I get $1 = u(1,1,1) = \frac16(0+0+0+0+0+0) + 1 = 1$, seems find to me.

Comment: @MikeEarnest on my display, that line overflows and I can't see the $+1$ at end.... the equation now looks fine.

Comment: This is related to the three-player gambler's ruin problem. There are three players with $a,b,$ and $c$ coins. Each turn, a randomly chosen player gives a coin to a randomly chosen other player. $U(a,b,c)$ is the expected number of rounds until someone goes broke. [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233502833_A_Simple_Solution_to_a_Multiple_Player_Gambler's_Ruin_Problem) gives a nice formula for the expected number of rounds when the two remaining players continue playing after the first elimination. This obeys the same recurrence, with different boundary conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach only, not closed form.

For now, we restrict the discussion to $a,b,c \ge 0$ (i.e. $\in \mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$).

In the recurrence, all the $u(x,y,z)$ terms have the same sum $S = x+y+z$.  Therefore, the $\mathbb{N}^3$ grid is actually sliced into layers of the same sum, and one layer does not affect another layer at all.  (Geometrically, the layers are $\perp$ the "normal" vector $(1,1,1)$.)  Within each layer, the boundaries are zeros but the internal numbers are defined recursively.  Also, each layer is an *equilateral triangle*.

The $S=0$ layer consists of only $u(0,0,0) = 0$.

The $S=1$ layer consists of $u(0,0,1) = u(0,1,0) = u(1,0,0) = 0$.

The $S=2$ layer consists of $6$ points, all valued $0$.

The $S=3$ layer consists of $10$ points, and finally a non-zero value appears:

```
   0
  0 0
 0 p 0
0 0 0 0
```

We have $u(1,1,1) = p = 1 + {1\over 6}\cdot (0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0) = 1$.  Note that the $6$ terms in the RHS of the recurrence correspond to the $6$ surrounding points in the hexagonal grid.

The $S=4$ layer consists of $15$ points:

```
    0
   0 0
  0 q 0
 0 q q 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

We have $q = u(1,2,1) = u(2,1,1) = u(1,1,2) = 1+ {1\over 6}\cdot 2q \implies q = {3 \over 2}$.

The $S=5$ layer consists of $21$ points and is the first layer with $2$ different non-zero values.

```
     0
    0 0
   0 r 0
  0 s s 0
 0 r s r 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

We have $r = u(3,1,1) = u(1,3,1) = u(1,1,3) = 1+ {1\over 6} (2s)$ and $s = u(2,2,1) = u(2,1,2) = u(1,2,2) = 1+ {1\over 6}(2s + 2r)$.  Solving these simultaneous equations give $s = {12\over 5}, r = {9 \over 5}.$

So basically in each layer, there will be $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns.  I have no proof that the system is even solvable, but my gut feel says yes.  As for closed-form, I don't see any right now.  Also BTW, I *think* $n \approx 2S/3$ for large $S$, so we are talking about a large number of unknowns.

**[Update:** Actually I just realized that $u(a,b,c)$ can be interpreted as the expected no. of steps to hit the boundaries, starting from $(a,b,c)$, in an unbiased random walk on the hexagonal grid.  So I am pretty sure the system of $n$ equations is solvable, and in fact, I wonder if there might be a closed form based on reasoning about the random walk a different way. **]**

---

The OP says $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$.  IMHO this is ill-defined, or to be precise: "75%" ill-defined!  The layering concept still holds, except now each layer is infinite.  However, consider e.g. the $S=4$ layer again.  Including the negative coordinates, it looks like this:

```
      0   0
       0 0
        0
       0 0
      0 q 0
     0 q q 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0         0
  0           0
```

There are clearly $3$ infinite lines of zeros, and the triangle they enclose can be solved, but are the outside values well-defined?  In the sense that, there exists a *unique* infinite sequence (pattern) of values fitting the recurrence?  For now, I don't see any proof.

**[Update:** Again, if we interpret $u(a,b,c)$ as expected time to hit the boundaries, then they are indeed unique, even outside the triangle, although I wonder if the values might be infinite (my guess is not: this is still just a 2-D walk, albeit on a hex grid).  **]**

Having said that, the recurrence seems inspired by some kind of diffusion model, so maybe we can define the values that way.  I.e. start with all zeros, and just keep updating all values in parallel.  I don't see any proof this process will converge either, but maybe it will?

Anyway, if we accept that values outside the triangle are undefined, then how much is undefined?  Well, $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is naturally divided into $8$ octants, of which the $\mathbb{N}^3$ octant is well-defined, and by symmetry so is the $(-\mathbb{N})^3$ octant (where $a,b,c \le 0$).  The other $6$ octants are outside the triangles.  Hence: "75%" ill-defined.  :)

Comment: $U(a,b,c) = \frac{3abc}{a+b+c}$ will be a solution of the problem if one restrict the recurrence relations to work for $a,b,c > 0$.

Comment: that certainly fits the 3 values i found.  how to prove it works in general?  and more importantly (for me), how on earth do you find that solution??  wow!

Comment: $Lu := u(a,b,c) - \frac16(u(a+1,b-1,c)+..\cdots)$ is essentially a 2d-discrete Laplacian over planes with constant $a+b+c$. $Lu = 1$ is like a Poisson equation. It has a polynomial solution of the form $-\frac12(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ but the boundary condition doesn't match. Since we want $u = 0$ whenever $abc = 0$, I look for $Lu$ on polynomial function of the form $abcP(a,b,c)$ and notice $Lu = \frac{a+b+c}{3}$ for $u = abc$. The only problem is I cannot figure how to handle the case $a+b+c = 0$.

Comment: @achillehui - no wonder i couldnt find it; i have no idea about Laplacian nor Poisson equation.  in any case once you found the solution it can be easily proven to fit the recurrence.  do you want to write that up as an answer?  if not, i'm gonna UPDATE mine and credit you.

Comment: @achillehui - the case of $S=0$ is exactly the case of the "infinite triangular" regions opposite the vertices of the bounded triangle in any other $S$.  does the Laplacian give a suggestion for a closed form?  With the random walk interpretation, i would think there is indeed a unique solution with finite values.

Comment: Feel free to update your answer. Solution of Poisson type of equation in a bounded region with prescribed value on the boundary is usually unique. On unbounded region, it need not though I don't have any idea how to prove that in this specific case.